# Loading data from an html form to a realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am following a tutorial to learn how to load data from an html form to a collection in a realtime database in firebase; but for some reason at some point I hit an issue.

This is the contents of the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test Application</title>
    <style media="screen">
      ......
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="./init-firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

    Name: <input id='name' type='text' value=''><br/>
    URL: <input id='url' type='text' value=''><br/>
    <form id='adTF'>
      <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>

    <script>
    document.getElementById('adTF').addEventListener('submit',addElement)

    function addElement(event) {
      console.log('Inside addElement');
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('after-preventDefault');
      let url = document.getElementById('url').value;
      console.log('after-getElementById');
      let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      url = url.trim();
      name = name.trim();
      console.log('url:',url);
      console.log('name:',name);

      // The following line crashes.
      var dbReference = firebase.database().ref('MyList');
      console.log('after-dbRef');

      let newItem = dbReference.push({url:'url-123',name:'name-123'});
      console.log('after-push');
      newItem.set({'url':'url-123','name':'name-123'});
      console.log('after-set');
    } /* End of addElement */
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the contents of init-firebase.js

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "A.......A",
  authDomain: "myapp-6638jj.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://myapp-6638jj.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "myapp-6638jj",
  storageBucket: "myapp-6638jj.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "3.....6",
  appId: "1:....:web:.....",
  measurementId: "G-73RX..XES"
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

As indicated in the source of the index.html file; there is a crash when using:

```
var dbReference = firebase.database().ref('MyList');
```

Looking in the Debugger output, it seems to be a problem inside firebase.js.

Can somebody point out a way to solve this problem?

In case this may be useful, this is a screenshot of the call stack I see in the Web Console when the crash happens:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the realtime database, to be able to do that you need to add the following `script`:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize

---

```
  <body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="./init-firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, I know, but isn't it included inside the one I use (meaning firebase.js). Anyway I was using firebase-database.js before and it did not work, so I suspect the issue must be somewhere else. I'll try again to be safe and let you know.

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't make any difference. I still have the same issue.